# does heroku support php native C extension?

Tags: php, heroku, php-extension

I am running php on our server which runs apache and php 5.6. with custom native C extension.
I am thinking about migrating to heroku. Does heroku support php native C extension (.so)? I can't find any information about it.

I am currently using swig & compile .so to build php extension.

Tried to create ticket on heroku but it has to bind with app which I don't have right now. Hopefully can get the answer here.

Comment: No, they dont for obvious security reasons. Plus if you already have a server, dont migrate to something like Heroku, it's a serious downgrade.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois What do you mean by downgrade? Their performance is bad?

Comment: For one performance but you are very restricted. The usual stuff you got with free hosters. You are better off with renting a VPS where you can do whatever you want, install whatever you want.